# everything Pass but emails still go to the spam folder! I think it would be about hostname but not sure and don't know how to fix this

Tags: postfix, email-server, hosting, spf, dkim

I checked too many topics and answers tested too many things! but can't find a solution to my problem. I'm a newbie user and maybe didn't understand some answers well.
I need to fix this problem as soon as possible, so I created this topic and hope to find a clear (and easy to do) answer.
I'm using Virtualmin as mail and web server.
IP changed to `12.345.678.910`
domain changed to `mydomain.com`
raw zone:

```
; mydomain.com Dumped Thu Sep 26 07:48:41 2019
;
mydomain.com.   86400   IN  SOA ns1.he.net. hostmaster.he.net. (
                    2019092609  ;serial
                    86400       ;refresh
                    7200        ;retry
                    3600000     ;expire
                    86400   )   ;minimum
mydomain.com.   3600    IN  A   12.345.678.910
mydomain.com.   3600    IN  NS  ns1.he.net.
mydomain.com.   3600    IN  NS  ns2.he.net.
mydomain.com.   3600    IN  MX  10 mail.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:12.345.678.910/32 -all"
_dmarc.mydomain.com.    300 IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; pct=100; p=quarantine; adkim=r; aspf=r"
mail.mydomain.com.  3600    IN  A   12.345.678.910
www.mydomain.com.   3600    IN  A   12.345.678.910
key._domainkey.mydomain.com.    3600    IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=key )
```

`PTR` has been set on `mail.mydomain.com`
`SMTP` works fine (using thunderbird to send messages)
`https://mxtoolbox.com` checked and all errors solved.
`https://www.mail-tester.com` got 10/10.
`https://appmaildev.com/en/dkim` everything Pass

`original mail in gmail`
SPF:    PASS with IP 12.345.678.910 Learn more
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain mydomain.com Learn more
DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more

```
Delivered-To: testingmail@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a1c:a891:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r139csp1564644wme;
        Thu, 26 Sep 2019 08:18:21 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqygH8PjdOkQW09orM3iSqTtZcC2oQjhwtP88nMdhMiznjGZzhG+Qp0OpKSakQ2gXTVkEUrJ
X-Received: by 2002:a1c:e008:: with SMTP id x8mr3369089wmg.85.1569511101641;
        Thu, 26 Sep 2019 08:18:21 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1569511101; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        keys
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        keys
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com header.s=2019 header.b=N+Lzr0yv;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 12.345.678.910 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
Return-Path: <support@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com. [12.345.678.910])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id p8si1812998wrt.517.2019.09.26.08.18.21
        for <testingmail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Thu, 26 Sep 2019 08:18:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 12.345.678.910 as permitted sender) client-ip=12.345.678.910;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com header.s=2019 header.b=N+Lzr0yv;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 12.345.678.910 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
Received: from [192.168.1.105] (unknown [151.243.44.80]) by mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id D5017A3F53 for <testingmail@gmail.com>; Thu, 26 Sep 2019 16:18:19 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com; keys.
     zgdZicdOospHQ==
To: testingmail@gmail.com
From: Franck <support@mydomain.com>
Subject: fact to read
Message-ID: <ed27f32e-e15d-a9e0-fbc4-7e2f1660a015@mydomain.com>
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 18:48:15 +0330
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/68.1.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US

Venus was once habitable until a mysterious event occurred. Venus likely 
sustained stable temperatures and hosted liquid water for billions of 
years until something triggered the release of carbon dioxide from rocks 
on the planet about 700 million years ago.
```

etc/host:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   lubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
##12.345.678.910    mydomain.com    mydomain
12.345.678.910  mail.mydomain.com   mail
```

etc/hostnames:

```
mail.mydomain.com
```

dig -x 12.345.678.910 +short

```
mail.mydomain.com.
```

Comment: You could try to have a look at what google postmaster tools report about this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174

Comment: What does Google say about the message?

Comment: @michael-hampton  "Lots of messages from mydomain.com were identified as spam in the past." it's a new domain and I just sent some message to my Gmail for testing mail-server

Comment: It may be new to you, but have you considered the possibility that someone else had the domain previously, and sent spam with it?

Comment: @michael-hampton we have this domain about 2 years (not used before a month ago) I don't think it was active before this 2 years

Comment: @MrSmile - did you finally figure this out? we have the same issue

Comment: @Kannaj Try posting a new question. Be sure to include the related entries in `/var/log/mail.log`.